# How do I parse a file like this, and define the variables?

Tags: text-processing

Example file:

```
/Variable1=Value1/Variable2=Value Value Value/Variable3=Value3 Value3/
```

I want it to read the variables and set them. Meaning I would be able to type `echo $Variable1` and get `Value1` as the output, etc. I tried a lot of things, but they were very long, and didn't work when the variables changed names. Does anyone know an effective method for this?

Comment: We may be able to help you to *implement a parser*, but we can't tell you *how to parse it*: what are the tokens and delimiters?

Comment: I assume you want to set "Variable1=Value1", "Variable2=Value Value Value", and "Variable3=Value3 Value3"  by reading the file somehow?

Comment: Can you also clarify the environment you want them set in? (which shell or scripting language)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `bash` starting point:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=/; set -f
for piece in $(cat file)
do
  var=$(echo "$piece" | cut -d= -f1)
  val=$(echo "$piece" | cut -d= -f2-)
  [ -n "$var" ] && eval $var=\"$val\"
done
IFS="$OIFS"
unset piece var val
```

While it skips empty variable names, this doesn't do any sanity-checking of the variable names themselves.

Second way, since I was determined to find a way to do it with `read`:

```
declare -a vars
IFS=/ read -a vars < file
for piece in ${vars[*]}
do 
  mangle=$(echo "$piece" | sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/')
  eval $mangle
done
unset vars piece mangle
```

The mangle line is just there to quote the value after the equals-sign.

Comment: You can just use `declare "$piece"` without mangling.

Comment: @glennjackman - the real trouble with that is what `$piece` is - it might be `TERM=` or `PATH=` or `PS4=`. the question is how to *parse* - validation ought to go along with that.

Answer (score 1):

similar to Jeff Schaller's answer:

```
IFS=/; set -f
set -- $(tr /\\n \\n/ <file |
         sed -ne's/^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*=/_&/p' |
         tr /\\n \\n/)
for v do eval "${v%%=*}=\${v#*=}"; done
```

Comment: Why are you prepending each line with `_` ?

Comment: @PSkocik - because `$_PATH` isn't `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

```
. <(
    awk '
      BEGIN{RS="/";FS="="}
      NF==2{printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2}
    ' file
)
```

This one uses `awk` to make the following text:

```
Variable1="Value1"
Variable2="Value Value Value"
Variable3="Value3 Value3"
```

This is sourced, so `Variable{1,2,3}` are available in `sh`.

Some points: The values are assumed to not contain ant `/`, `=`, or `"`.

Comment: or `$` and especially not `$(...)` - and the names can be anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$Variable1" "$Variable2" "$Variable3"



$ cat file
/Variable1=Value1/Variable2=Value Value Value/Variable3=Value3 Value3/ 
$ source <(tr / "\n" < file | sed -r 's/=(.*)/="\1"/')
$ printf "%s\n" "$Variable1" "$Variable2" "$Variable3"
Value1
Value Value Value
Value3 Value3
```

Comment: you should handle `"`.

Answer (score 0):

For bash: (if your string is in a file called 'liste.txt')

```
IFS="/"
for val in $(cat liste.txt); do echo "$val" | sed -r "s/=(.*)$/=\"\1\"/g" | eval; done
```

After, you just have to try:

```
echo "$Varaible1"
echo "$Variable2"
```

and so on

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)